# How to remove view in CallScreeningService with WindowManager?

Tags: android, view, service

I create a view in onScreenCall with function showCallInfoView and it appears:

```
override fun onScreenCall(details: Call.Details) {
    if (details.callDirection == Call.Details.DIRECTION_INCOMING) {
        details.handle?.schemeSpecificPart?.let { phoneNumber ->
            Log.d("phoneNumber", "phoneNumber======$phoneNumber")
            if (phoneNumber.isNotEmpty()) {
                showCallInfoView(phoneNumber, blackList)
                respondToCall(details, CallResponse.Builder().build())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I try to remove view according to a state:

```
when (state) {
                TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                    mainHandler.post {
                        Log.d("CALL_STATE_IDLE-1", "CALL_STATE_IDLE")
                        windowManager?.removeView(customView)
                    }

                }
```

But it doesn't work.

I tried to use `val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`, but it doesn't help.

How to do it?